# Проблема с проверкой файла на существование

Tags: python

```
def __init__(self):
    self.csvfile = input("Enter the name of .csv file : ")
    if not os.path.exists(self.csvfile):
        print("File doesn't exist")
        self.__init__()
```

При любом вводе - переходит на ветку с print("File doesn't exist")[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом файл находится в той-же директории, что и скрипт[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Рабочую директорию проверь

Comment: @eri Да,  в этом была проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CWD оказалась ветка на уровень выше, потому файл не находился в зоне видимости.

Проверил:
from os import getcwd